# How to detect facial landmarks in UWP

Tags: uwp, face-detection

I want to write a UWP on Windows10 to detect facial landmarks.
Anybody can recommend me a suitable API?

Many thanks.

YL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/) by Microsoft for example. With the Vision Api you can detect faces for example and you are getting more information if needed.

Comment: Cognitive Services is a cloud based API. If my application will run in an environment without network. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It is a cloud base api. Do you need an offline functionality in your app?

Comment: Yes. I need offline functionalities.

Comment: It looks DLIB is a good at facial landmark detection. But I am not sure  if I can use it in UWP.

Comment: I’m not totally sure, but take look at here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.faceanalysis.facedetector

Comment: FaceDetector only detects the face and returns a face bounding box, but does not detect landmarks.